# Get milliseconds from epoch via HTTP

Tags: api, http, timestamp, epoch

I am working on a microcontroller and don't want to keep track of time with the system clock. I want to make an HTTP request to get the current time in milliseconds from the epoch (1970). I already know how to form all the requests, I just can't find a url that can return this data to me. Who offers this as an API? I don't want to make an https request.

Comment: The request itself may take multiple milliseconds to run - by the time you have the answer, it's probably wrong anyway. Given this, do you not think it's optimistic to want to get the time to that level of accuracy?

Comment: Oh there is no way that I will achieve millisecond accuracy with an http request, but I don't care as much about the accuracy. Within a minute is accurate enough for my application

Comment: Well, if "to the minute" is accurate enough, practically *every* http server on the web will include a `Date` header in its response. You don't need a dedicated endpoint for this.

Comment: Ya I wish the Date header was in milliseconds, but it is not. This is the date header when requesting google.com: `"date": "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 06:32:50 GMT"` That would be very expensive for me to convert.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have a site called [Current Millis](http://currentmillis.com) and theoretically infinite bandwidth. I think i can quickly write a php, say www.currentmillis.com/api/millis-since-epoch.php. Is this ok for you?

UPDATE: It was infinite bandwidth but not infinite resources.. Because the server can not hope to sustain millions of HTTP requests to a service that resolves time to the millisecond, that URL has been discontinued..  Instead minutes since epoch are offered now: http://currentmillis.com/time/minutes-since-unix-epoch.php (because within 1 minute the value can be cahced by the host server)

Comment: Actually, i just made it, it was too simple :) [Milliseconds since epoch](http://currentmillis.com/api/millis-since-epoch.php)

Comment: I will use it forever!

Comment: Cool. If you have any other such 'API' suggestions please let me know, this looks like a fun area i can extend my site into.

Comment: 404 page not found, do you still maintain this site?

Is it as simple as <?php echo time(); ?>

Comment: It's still maintained but it has become so used (millions of HTTP requests per day) that it can't offer millisecond resolution anymore, the host server went down many times.. What is offered now is [Minutes since epoch](http://currentmillis.com/time/minutes-since-unix-epoch.php) (because for at least one minute they are cacheable by the server)

Comment: Damnit! That millseconds since epoch endpoint was exactly what I was looking for :(. Does anyone know if a simlar service exists elsewhere?

Comment: I discovered http://now.httpbin.org/ which contains a pretty easily-parsable live-updating milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: Is that site yours? Wow, One of the most useful site... Thank you for your service @Sandman

Answer (score 1):

https://now.httpbin.org/ is great for this - it returns a JSON array of the current time in different time formats, including time since epoch to a ridiculously small fraction of a second:

```sh
$ curl -s http://now.httpbin.org/
{"now": {"epoch": 1547752567.4569337, "slang_date": "today", "slang_time": "now", "iso8601": "2019-01-17T19:16:07.456934Z", "rfc2822": "Thu, 17 Jan 2019 19:16:07 GMT", "rfc3339": "2019-01-17T19:16:07.45Z"}, "urls": ["/", "/docs", "/when/:human-timestamp", "/parse/:machine-timestamp"]}
```

JSON should be easily parsable in any language, but if you're simply using a unix command-line then [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a great utility for it:

```sh
$ curl -s http://now.httpbin.org/ | jq
{
  "now": {
    "epoch": 1547752558.6447814,
    "slang_date": "today",
    "slang_time": "now",
    "iso8601": "2019-01-17T19:15:58.644781Z",
    "rfc2822": "Thu, 17 Jan 2019 19:15:58 GMT",
    "rfc3339": "2019-01-17T19:15:58.64Z"
  },
  "urls": [
    "/",
    "/docs",
    "/when/:human-timestamp",
    "/parse/:machine-timestamp"
  ]
}

$ curl -s http://now.httpbin.org/ | jq '.now.epoch'
1547752585.5284808
```

Comment: Is the service still available? The now.httpbin.org subdomain doesn't seem resolvable anymore.

Comment: It's still not working .. someone has an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The rest api found at http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ should work as long as you know your location.
For example, if you are on the east coast use
http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/New_York.
Alternativly
http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/UTC will return UTC time
this api should only be used to calculate an offset from your current system time. After you have the offset, you should just use your system time in whatever language you are programming in and add the offset, so this endpoint does not experiance a DOS attack from people trying to make rest calls every few miliseconds.